# Toshiba Satellite (A660-11M) won't boot USB flash drive or a DVD for Windows installation

Tags: windows, boot, usb, bios

I've bought myself a new SSD for my secondary laptop (Toshiba Satellite A660-11M), due to a corrupted HDD.

After installing the SSD I've tried my bootable Windows 10 USB flash drive I always use but nothing happened. He discovers the Stick but the laptop is never able to boot it. I've tried 3 different USB flash drives and 4 different Windows ISOs. Also I used also Rufus and the Windows media creation tool.

My BIOS Settings don't show the Option for "secure boot" or a switch between UEFI and LEGACY. They just don't exist and even setting a Supervisor password didn't change anything. (Also I'm not able to update the BIOS due to a missing battery).

The really strange part is, that he also doesn't recognize any Windows 10 DVD. I could give that machine whatever I want and he won't boot anything.

Also no Linux live distribution of any kind has worked yet.

I've made a Windows 10 installation on the same laptop on the old HDD not more than 4 weeks ago. Everything worked fine then.

So does anybody have an idea how I can install Windows on this laptop?

Comment: What's the boot device priority? Maybe it's using the hard drive first, ignoring everything else. Is there a one-time boot menu (from pressing some button when booting)?

Comment: I can order the Boot order as i wish and he definitly tries to boot from the Stick or DVD but is never able to do so

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not supported on all Toshiba websites. I have managed to find it on [Toshiba Ireland](https://web.archive.org/web/20161222182354/http://www.toshiba.ie/discontinued-products/satellite-a660-11m/), where I found a BIOS update from February 2012. Check if this is newer than yours before installing.

A possible explanation for your being unable to boot is that your computer
needs a UEFI boot USB/DVD.

You may use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/downloads/) for creating it,
and you may need Windows 64-bit ISO.

Note that you need to format the disk on the Toshiba with GPT partitioning
for using UEFI.

Comment: I've used Rufus (with the UEFI settings) and i also found the newest Bios version on the irish toshiba site. But this doesnt't change the fact, that i need a functional battery to start the Bios update.